# Search array of objects inside ant design table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects, antd

I have a table with multiple columns, in one of the columns, the dataindex is an array of objects similar to this,

```
"assignedTeams": [
  {
    "teamType": {
      "id": "43123",
      "name": "Team A"
    }
  },
  {
    "teamType": {
      "id": "23421",
      "name": "Team B"
    }
  },
  {
    "teamType": {
      "id": "12345",
      "name": "Team C"
    }
  }
]
```

I use the ant designs table render method to extract the name and display it in the table.
My question is, How to implement a custom search here so that I can filter out by the name.

Below is the code for my custom search function, which only works for strings, not the array of objects as I have shown above.

```
export const GetArrayObjectsColumnSearchProps = (dataIndex) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('')
  const [searchedColumn, setSearchedColumn] = useState('')
  let searchInput = ''

  const handleSearch = (selectedKeys, confirm) => {
    // console.log('selectedKeys', selectedKeys, 'dataIndex', dataIndex)
    confirm()
    setSearchText(selectedKeys[0])
    setSearchedColumn(dataIndex)
  }

  const handleReset = (clearFilters) => {
    clearFilters()
    setSearchText('')
  }
  return {
    filterDropdown: ({ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters }) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <Input
          ref={(node) => {
            searchInput = node
          }}
          placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          onChange={(e) => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])}
          onPressEnter={() => handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
          style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: 'block' }}
        />
        <Space>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
            icon={<SearchOutlined />}
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Search
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => handleReset(clearFilters)} size="small" style={{ width: 90 }}>
            Reset
          </Button>
        </Space>
      </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: (filtered) => (
      <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined }} />
    ),
    onFilter: (value, record) => {
      return get(record, dataIndex) ? find(get(record, dataIndex), { title: value }) : ''
    },
    onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: (visible) => {
      if (visible) {
        setTimeout(() => searchInput.select(), 100)
      }
    },
    render: (textArray) => {
      // console.log('textArr', textArray, 'searchedColumn=', searchedColumn, 'dataIndex=', dataIndex)
      return isEqual(searchedColumn, dataIndex) ? (
        <div>
          {textArray
            ? textArray.map((text) => {
                // console.log('text NOT equal', text)
                return (
                  // color={text.color}
                  <Tag key={text.key}>{text.title}</Tag>
                )
              })
            : ''}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          {textArray
            ? textArray.map((text) => {
                // console.log('text NOT equal', text)
                return <Tag key={text.key}>{text.title}</Tag> // color={text.color}
              })
            : ''}
        </div>
      )
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an optional parameter in `GetArrayObjectsColumnSearchProps`. Let's called that parameter as `objectPath`.
In `onFilter`, you can check if you have `objectPath` then get all the values from the array using the `objectPath` and check for the value if it's exist or not. If `objectPath` not defined, you can search for string values.

```
let dataIndexValues = get(record, dataIndex);
return objectPath
    ? dataIndexValues
          .map((item: any) => get(item, objectPath, '').toLowerCase())
          .join()
          .includes(value)
    : find(get(record, dataIndex));
```